# how to avoid a dependency to load in spark-streaming and kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I'm trying to get an example of kafka and spark-streaming working and I find problems when running the process.

this is the exception:

> [error] Caused by:
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Incompatible
>   Jackson version: 2.9.8

This is the build.sbt:

```
name := "SparkJobs"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

val sparkVersion = "2.4.1"

val flinkVersion = "1.7.2"

resolvers ++= Seq(
"Typesafe Releases" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/",
"apache snapshots" at "http://repository.apache.org/snapshots/",
"confluent.io" at "http://packages.confluent.io/maven/",
"Maven central" at "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/"
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion,
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion,
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10" % sparkVersion,
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % sparkVersion

// ,"org.apache.flink" %% "flink-connector-kafka-0.10" % flinkVersion
, "org.apache.kafka" %% "kafka-streams-scala" % "2.2.0"
// , "io.confluent" % "kafka-streams-avro-serde" % "5.2.1"
)

//excludeDependencies ++= Seq(
// commons-logging is replaced by jcl-over-slf4j
//  ExclusionRule("jackson-module-scala", "jackson-module-scala")
//
)
```

This is the [code](https://pastebin.com/0DFQgrYb)

Doing a sbt dependencyTree I can see that `spark-core_2.11-2.4.1.jar` has `jackson-databind-2.6.7.1`, and it is telling me that it is evicted by `2.9.8 version`, which it suggest that there is a collision between libraries, but `spark-core_2.11-2.4.1.jar` is not the only one, `kafka-streams-scala_2.11:2.2.0` uses `jackson-databind-2.9.8` version, so I don't know which library has to evict `jackson-databind-2.9.8.` Spark-core / kafka-streams-scala? or both?

How can I avoid jackson `library version 2.9.8` in order to get this task up and running?

I am assuming that I need `jackson-databind-2.6.7 version` ...

UPDATE with advices. Still not working.

I have deleted dependencies of kafka-stream-scala, which tries to use jackson 2.9.8, using this build.sbt

```
name := "SparkJobs"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

val sparkVersion = "2.4.1"

val flinkVersion = "1.7.2"

val kafkaStreamScala = "2.2.0"

resolvers ++= Seq(
"Typesafe Releases" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/",
"apache snapshots" at "http://repository.apache.org/snapshots/",
"confluent.io" at "http://packages.confluent.io/maven/",
"Maven central" at "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/"
)


libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion ,
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion,
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion,
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10" % sparkVersion,
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % sparkVersion

)
```

But i got new [exception](https://pastebin.com/yewDXtjT)

UPDATE 2

got it, now i understand the second exception, i forgot to awaitToTermination.

Comment: You should **not** include `kafka-streams-scala` as Kafka Streams is **not** compatible with Spark Streaming API.

Comment: Thank you @cricket_007, i removed kafka-streams-scala, but this exception happen: ERROR Utils: throw uncaught fatal error in thread spark-listener-group-shared. I updated the question with complete exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Kafka Streams includes Jackson 2.9.8](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.2/gradle/dependencies.gradle#L57)

But you don't need it when using Spark Streaming's Kafka Integration, so you should really just remove it.

Similarly, the `kafka-streams-avro-serde` isn't what you want to be using with Spark, rather you might find [AbraOSS/ABRiS](https://github.com/AbsaOSS/ABRiS/) useful instead.

Comment: Yes, i removed Kafka-streams and jackson-core-2.9.8.jar is not anymore. I removed too kafka-streams-avro-serde, it is not necessary at the moment and i will take into account AbraOSS/ABRIS library. Thanks. Still not working for now.